# Finding Value between two numbers in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframe "A" and "B". I would like to find out row number from "B" where value of "A" lies in between two numbers of "B" data frame.

Table A

| Index | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.084 |
| 1 | 0.169 |
| 2 | 0.252 |
| 3 | 0.337 |
| 4 | 0.419 |
| 5 | 0.504 |
| 6 | 0.589 |

Table B

| Index | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.071 |
| 1 | 0.167 |
| 2 | 0.244 |
| 3 | 0.320 |

In the case of the above tables let's take one example. The First Number from Table "A" is 0.084 it's Actually in between Table B 0 & 1 Index value i.e. 0.071 and 0.167. I am looking out for an output as [0,1] which is basically row numbers of two values.

Comment: How do you decide 0.084 is between 0.071 & 0.167? It can be in between anything. It is also in between 0.071 & 0.320 or in case any number upper or lower.

Comment: @Abhishek It's all about finding the first two numbers between it lie. Of course, your suggestion is valid but the first two best combinations are what I am looking out for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First initialize empty array for result:

```
res = [[]] * len(A.iloc[:, 0])
```

Then we implement nested loop through A and B, and check each value in A is between B values and return the index

The condition return the start index only:

```
(A.iloc[:, 0][i] > B.iloc[:, 0][j]) & (A.iloc[:, 0][i] < B.iloc[:, 0][j+1])
```

So I get the value and add 1 to it later and add them to a list:

```
res[i]=([j , j+1])
```

The full code:

```
import pandas as pd

A = [0.084, 0.169, 0.252, 0.337, 0.419, 0.504, 0.589]
B = [0.071, 0.167, 0.244, 0.320]

A = pd.DataFrame(A)
B = pd.DataFrame(B)

res = [[]] * len(A.iloc[:, 0])

for i in range(0, len(A.iloc[:, 0])):
    for j in range(0, len(B.iloc[:, 0])-1):
        if (A.iloc[:, 0][i] > B.iloc[:, 0][j]) & (A.iloc[:, 0][i] < B.iloc[:, 0][j+1]):
            res[i]=([j , j+1])

print(res)
```

The output:
[image]

Note: I assume that B is always sorted in ascending order

Comment: Thanks @Ola Galal for your help, it's really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `B` is sorted in ascending order, and that the bins are non-overlapping. To bin a value, you can first take the difference between that value and boundaries of all available bins. The desired bin is then found at index `i` where the difference is positive at `i` but transits to negative at `i+1`.

```
def apply_fn(x):
    delta = x.iloc[:,1] - x.iloc[:,3]
    mask = delta.ge(0) & delta.shift(-1).lt(0)  # True where transit happens
    return x[mask]

A = pd.DataFrame([0.084, 0.169, 0.252, 0.337, 0.419, 0.504, 0.589])
B = pd.DataFrame([0.071, 0.167, 0.244, 0.320])
C = A.reset_index().join(B.reset_index(), lsuffix='_A', rsuffix='_B', how='cross')
D = C.groupby('index_A').apply(apply_fn).reset_index(drop=True)[['index_A', 'index_B']]
D['index_B'] = [[i, i+1] for i in D['index_B'].tolist()]
print(D)
```

Output

```
    index_A index_B
0   0   [0, 1]
1   1   [1, 2]
2   2   [2, 3]
```